# PHP Website - Twitter API + Abraham Oauth (Unable to find x_rate_limit_remaining )

Tags: php, api, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I was developing a simple function to get the id's of my twitters followers. I am able to login using oauth and get the results but I am not able to get the headers info so that I can use the x_rate_limit_remaining value from the headers.
The function is :

```
    function get_id_of_followers() {
        $access_token = $_SESSION['access_token'];
        $connection = new TwitterOauth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);
        $data0 = get_class_methods($connection);
        echo "<pre> D0 ", print_r($data0, true), "</pre>";
        $data1 = $connection->getLastXHeaders();
        echo "<pre> D1 ", print_r($data1, true), "</pre>";
        $data2 = $connection->getLastXHeaders()["x_rate_limit_remaining"];
// x_rate_limit_remaining is an entity in the headers that I am able to see with my python scripts in headers output.
        echo "<pre> D2 ", $data2, "</pre>";
        $data3 = $connection->get('followers/ids');
        echo "<pre> D3 ", print_r($data3, true), "</pre>";
    }
```

The Output from the function is as follows:

```
 D0
Array
(
    [0] => __construct
    [1] => setOauthToken
    [2] => getLastApiPath
    [3] => getLastHttpCode
    [4] => getLastXHeaders
    [5] => getLastBody
    [6] => resetLastResponse
    [7] => url
    [8] => oauth
    [9] => oauth2
    [10] => get
    [11] => post
    [12] => delete
    [13] => put
    [14] => upload
    [15] => setTimeouts
    [16] => setDecodeJsonAsArray
    [17] => setUserAgent
    [18] => setProxy
    [19] => setGzipEncoding
)


D1 
Array
(
)


 D2 

D3 
stdClass Object
(
    [ids] => Array
        (
            [0] => 730017479360045056
            [1] => 4716372642
            [2] => 709411090980020224
            [3] => 4905437529
            [4] => 709964576868200449
            [5] => 228648311
            [6] => 3190604329
            [7] => 4298659035
            [8] => 378112124
            [9] => 4554579372
            [10] => 3845238492
            [11] => 3009354738
records retrived upto 5000
```

Now I am able to get the response(D3) however, Why is my headers(D2) array returning as null ? Am I missing something ? 
(Question also posted at https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/issues/469)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making a very small mistake of trying to get the headers before making the request. Try this code (I am removing all the unwanted stuff from code)

```
function get_id_of_followers() {
        $access_token = $_SESSION['access_token'];
        $connection = new TwitterOauth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);
        $Body = $connection->get('followers/ids');
        $Header = $connection->getLastXHeaders();
        echo "<pre> Body: ", print_r($Body, true), "</pre>";
        echo "<pre> Header: ", print_r($Header, true), "</pre>";
        echo "<pre> x_rate_limit_remaining: ", $Header[x_rate_limit_remaining], "</pre>";
}
```

All you had to do was to call the `$connection->getLastXHeaders();` after the `$connection->get('followers/ids');` call for things to work.

Comment: freaks!! This thing worked like a charm..!! 
I was trying to print the http headers before making the http call. What an absolute blunder.